# forceChatter:feed & forceChatter:publisher components is not loading in VF page using lightning out

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

This is my feed component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" access="global">
    <forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="XYZ...."/>
</aura:component>
```

Publisher component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" description="Sample Component" access="global">
    <forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="XYZ...."/>
</aura:component>
```

VF:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning/>
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:forceChatter", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:forceChatterfeed",{},"lightning",function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:forceChatterpublisher",{},"lightning",function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          }); 
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

The issue is when I am using these components in my VF page using Lightning out, its not loading/rendering properly (Not even able to comment & Attach document). But when I am adding these components in record edit page using App Builder its displaying properly and working fine.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I don't think forceChatter:feed and forceChatter:publisher are supported outside of Lightning Experience and Communities, according to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_publisher.htm.

Comment: I agree with Diana, already had the issue and it's not supported. You should write it as an answer so that it could be selected as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BETA forceChatter:fullFeed component will bring through the JS required for forceChatter:publisher to work.

Don't use the forceChatter:feed component- as stated in the comments- this isn't supported outside of LEX or Lightning Communities.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_fullFeed.htm